# Can we POST the data present in json format using wget in linux

Tags: json, linux, post, wget

I want to know is there a possibility to post the data in json format to a dashboard from linux server.
My JSON data is in the below format.

```json
{
    "data":"{\"actiontodo\":\"Action to do for test nr: 
     1\",\"critical\":\"LOW\",\"fixstatus\":\"NOTCONCERN\",\"host\":\"MTR_SOME_HOST\",
     \"message\":\"$message\",\"mgsApplication\":\"MTR\",\"sMxtype\":\"PROD\",
     \"scriptname\":\"$scriptname\"}",
    "msg":"NotificationReceiveDTO without dict to send at: 2020-06-07T11:14:09.794 Created at: 2020- 
     06-07T11:14:09.797",
    "msgType":"DATA"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what your research of the `wget` man page revealed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

From the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options-1) for `wget` it is possible to post data to website, using either the `--post-data=string` or `--post-file=file` argument.

Comment: This is true. However, please note that the preferred way now is to use the long form, `--method=POST --body-data=<data>` or `--body-file=file`. This also opens up the possibility to send any othertype of request